# How do I access an entity behind my aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am into my first week of DDD and have a couple of entities with aggregate roots defined.

I read that no external entity outside of an aggregate can reference an entity in an aggregate, so the external entity has to reference the aggregate root.

Well, unless I have modelled my solution incorrectly I need a reference to an entity behind the aggregate root. How do I handle this situation or do I have to remodel my domain to avoid this situation?

JD

Comment: Seeing some code would help with answering this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably could refine your model. If an external reference to an entity inside your aggregate is required, then that is a strong indicator that the internal entity might be an aggregate root itself.

This of course is general advice since I don't know anything about your specific model.

For great advice concerning aggregate design, have a look at this [paper by Vaughn Vernon](http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/vernon_2011). In Part I, "Modeling of an Aggregate", he specifically addresses aggregate granularity which I found very enlightening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I found was that I started to think of my entity as an aggregate root and then I found I had a lot of aggregate roots referencing aggregate roots which I suppose is fine as I will most likely use repositories to access them. Does this sound right?

Comment: I don't entirely agree with the first paragraph. I've found that "aggregate id + local (to the aggregate) entity id" can be communicated to the outside and tracked inside another aggregate. It's not a general recommendation, but it can be useful.

Comment: @Yves, thanks for your recommendation. What if we have a deep graph, and the local entity is several objects deep in? So what would I track (all the entry objects ids)?

Comment: As Dennis mentioned, this needs to be viewed in light of what aggregates actually are (cfr. the white paper). If you truly require a large cluster of entities to be consistent, then you can put them inside the same aggregate (again, highly contextual). Depth is a structural thing and IMO irrelevant in this discussion. An aggregate is responsible for tracking all state required to enforce consistency and future behavior. I do think, should you rephrase your question using an example, it would be much easier to give you sound advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dynamic Aggregate
Dynamic aggregate allows you to combine aggregates and load them dynamically at runtime. Dynamic aggregate makes it possible to load data from different aggregates at high speed without changing the primary aggregates. When reading data from different aggregates, it is recommended to use Dynamic aggregate to reduce the number of I/O.

For more details see this repository.
[git Repository](https://github.com/RahimLotfiGH/AUAFramework.Net8_CQRS)